# Display corrupted with repeated scrollbar in SSMS Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) corrupts the display results and query window in both versions 2005 and 2008 as shown in the screenshot.  It seems like the window drawing / re-drawing display system repeats the scroll bars and does not draw / re-draw the content areas.  This occurs on Windows 7 x64 on both a 2-monitor setup on a workstation and on a laptop.

**UPDATE Q1 2011: MS has tagged this with "Active" on its issue tracker at [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/533311/display-corruption-on-ssms-at-large-resolutions-on-second-screen).**

**UPDATE Q2 2011: Bug reproduced on NVidia (2) and Radeon hardware**

A few add-ons such as Tabs Studio and a few screen capture utilities are in use, but the behavior persists even if these are disabled and/or unloaded and on reboot.

My question is if this is caused by something that is within my control and how the behavior may be fixed.  In the meantime I am using Linqpad (wonderful) but we still need to use SSMS for a number of reasons and this is driving us nuts.

At least one other person has had this happen and has posted on MS's connect site, but it has not be resolved or address by MS as far as I can tell.

[image: Here is a nice screenshot of the issue]

Comment: You may have better luck asking this on SuperUser since it's related to a software bug and not to programming.  My suspicion is that it's OS or video driver related.

Comment: This is a common problem in mgmt studio. I have it from time to time and I know several people at work who have the same issue.

Comment: Never used 2008, but I've been using 2005 since, well, around 2005, and I've never seen that happen. Something odd like a problem with a particular video driver, maybe?

Comment: I thought so, too, but have used two different machines (desktop and laptop) with two different video cards (NVidia GeForce GTS 250, NVidia 9300M GS -- two common platforms?) and the problem persists.  I know I'm in the minority here though since MS has not fixed the problem... The problem did not occur under WinXP on either machine.

Comment: Honestly, I'll buy a new video card if it'll fix the problem.  While not a programming problem per-se, this is definitely getting in the way of my programming.

Comment: As a temporary solution, would it help if you switched to the basic visual style? (I'm not daring to suggest the classic one, even if I myself use it daily.)

Comment: I have this!!! started only a week ago - was fine til then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an identified bug in SSMS per http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/533311/display-corruption-on-ssms-at-large-resolutions-on-second-screen

No workarounds have been identified.

Comment: very dead link. microsoft connnect has been retired

Comment: Microsoft Connect has been retired to get rid of all the annoying bugs they have to fix

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well (SSMS 2008 R2, Win 7 64 bit, 3 screens, NVIDIA Quadro NVS 420).

The workaround that fixed the problem for me was was to change the 'Compatibility Settings' for Ssms.exe. Check the Setting: 'Disable display scaling on high DPI settings'.

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR6pr.jpg

Next time SSMS opened, no more annoying scrolling bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem in SSMS2008R2. A quick fix is to drag a Splitter between ObjectExplorer and SQLEditor. SSMS re-paints itself then and display is at least correct. Works with about 75% probability. :)